# Function of unlist() when turning one row of a dataframe to a matrix

Tags: r

What is the difference between matrix(unlist(DF[1,])) and matrix(DF[1,]) where DF is my dataframe. How does unlist() help here?

Answer (score 0):

`DF[1,]` will extract the first row of the data.frame. This row is still a data.frame, a type of list. `unlist()` will convert it to a vector that can be made into a matrix. If you don't use `unlist`, the you can still make a matrix, but it is a matrix of the elements of the list, rather than of the elements of a vector. For example,

```
> cars[1,]
  speed dist
1     4    2
> a <- matrix(cars[1,])
> b <- matrix(unlist(cars[1,]))
> a[,1]
[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 2

> b[,1]
[1] 4 2
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Thank you for the answer. 
 matrix(unlist(DF[1,]))
and 
 matrix(as.vector(DF[1,])) 
serve the same function?

Comment: The output might look similar, but they will behave differently when you subset them. You probably want to unlist()

Comment: Okay. Thanks alot!